# Postgres выборка YYYY-MM

Tags: sql, postgresql

как сделать запрос вида

SELECT 
      *
    FROM 
      t where "F_Date"::month() > '2015-12' and "F_Date"::month() < '2016-02'

я знаю про to_char

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  "SC_Tag"."T_TagData" where to_char("F_Date", 'YYYY-MM') > '2015-12' and to_char("F_Date", 'YYYY-MM') < '2016-02'
```

но думаю там большие накладные расходы на преобразование?

Comment: а просто `...where "F_Date" >= '2016-01-01' and "F_Date" < '2016-02-01'` сделать нельзя? с postgresql раньше не работал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вы правы, накладные расходы на преобразование to_char приличные, впрочем, как и любое другое преобразование данных, включая гипотетические "F_Date"::month(). Составляя запрос надо стараться выполнить преобразование статичных данных запроса (т.е. параметров) к тому виду, который хранится в базе. Преобразование параметров будет выполнено один раз, а любое преобразование колонки таблицы в where будет выполнено для каждой строки. Кроме того, использование любой функции к колонке делает невозможным использование индексов, даже если они есть. Т.е. преобразование данных из колонки гарантировано приводит к полному сканировнию таблицы.

Ваш запрос можно переписать так:

```
select *
  from "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
 where "F_Date" between to_date('2015-12', 'YYYY-MM') + interval '1 month'
                    and to_date('2016-02', 'YYYY-MM') - interval '1 day'
```

Comment: а  where "F_Date" = to_date('2016-01', 'YYYY-MM') аналогично отработает?

Comment: смотря что от него требуется, to_date(2016-01) даст 1 января 2016. а если нужен целый месяц то такой же between от 2016-01 до +1 month - 1 day (что бы последний день месяца получить